# Cassandra indexes vs materialized view

Tags: cassandra

I have next Cassandra table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ringostat.hits (
  hitId uuid,
  clientId VARCHAR,
  session MAP<VARCHAR, TEXT>,
  traffic MAP<VARCHAR, TEXT>,
  PRIMARY KEY (hitId, clientId)
);

INSERT INTO ringostat.hits (hitId, clientId, session, traffic)
  VALUES('550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000'. 'clientId', {'id': '1', 'number': '1', 'startTime': '1460023732', 'endTime': '1460023762'}, {'referralPath': '/example_path_for_example', 'campaign': '(not set)', 'source': 'www.google.com', 'medium': 'referal', 'keyword': '(not set)', 'adContent': '(not set)', 'campaignId': '', 'gclid': '', 'yclid': ''});

INSERT INTO ringostat.hits (hitId, clientId, session, traffic)
      VALUES('650e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000'. 'clientId', {'id': '1', 'number': '1', 'startTime': '1460023732', 'endTime': '1460023762'}, {'referralPath': '/example_path_for_example', 'campaign': '(not set)', 'source': 'www.google.com', 'medium': 'cpc', 'keyword': '(not set)', 'adContent': '(not set)', 'campaignId': '', 'gclid': '', 'yclid': ''});

INSERT INTO ringostat.hits (hitId, clientId, session, traffic)
      VALUES('750e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000'. 'clientId', {'id': '1', 'number': '1', 'startTime': '1460023732', 'endTime': '1460023762'}, {'referralPath': '/example_path_for_example', 'campaign': '(not set)', 'source': 'www.google.com', 'medium': 'referal', 'keyword': '(not set)', 'adContent': '(not set)', 'campaignId': '', 'gclid': '', 'yclid': ''});
```

I want to select all rows where `source='www.google.com'` AND `medium='referal'`.

```
SELECT * FROM hits WHERE traffic['source'] = 'www.google.com' AND traffic['medium'] = 'referal' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Without add `ALLOW FILTERING` I got error: `No supported secondary index found for the non primary key columns restrictions`.

That's why I see two options:

1. Create index on traffic column.
2. Create materialized view.
3. Create another table and set `INDEX` for `traffic` column.

Which is the best option ? Also, I have many fields with `MAP` type on which I will need to filter. What issues can be if on every field I will add `INDEX` ?

Thank You.

Comment: You should consider asking your final question as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [When to use an index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html).

> Do not use an index in these situations:
>
> - On high-cardinality columns because you then query a huge volume of records for a small number of results. [...] Conversely, creating an index on an extremely low-cardinality column, such as a boolean column, does not make sense.
> - In tables that use a counter column
> - On a frequently updated or deleted column.
> - To look for a row in a large partition unless narrowly queried.

If your planned usage meets one or more of these criteria, it is probably better to use a materialized view.

Comment: And in my materialized view I need to add index on my `traffic` column ?

Comment: No, the columns you are going to query with need to be in the PRIMARY KEY, in order.

Comment: But I have MAP type. I can't set PRIMARY KEY on this type :(

Comment: Then you have to use an index, or remodel your data. A materialised view won't help.

Comment: I think that separating `traffic` column in different columns like `traffic.source VARCHAR`, `traffic.medium VARCHAR` will help. Thank you :)